# How to access form data after submitting to a new URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to submit form details to a completely new URL on click of the submit button. This is in a React application. I have the basic setup of the form in the following manner.

```
    let form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action",'localhost:3000/message/');
    form.setAttribute("onSubmit", this.handleSubmit);
    form.setAttribute("target", 'newWindow');

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "message");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "Hi. Im Awesome");
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);

    window.open('localhost:3000/message/', 'newWindow');
    form.submit();
```

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

At this point when I submit, a new tab opens up at `localhost:3000/message` but that tab also makes a network request to `localhost:3000/message/` with the form data.

I want to stop the extra network call to `localhost:3000/message/` and I also want to be able to access the form data directly in the app running at 3000.

Is this achievable ?

**UPDATE**: As @Jite mentioned, fetch would clean up some of the issues here so instead of directly sending in the data as a form, I also tried sending it through the fetch api.

```
    window.open('localhost:3000/message/', 'newWindow');

    fetch('localhost:3000/message/', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Hi, I'm even more awesome!'
      })
    })
```

The render method of the app running at `localhost:3000\` is set up in the following manner-

```
  //import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Route
            path="/message"
            render={props =>     
              <h2>Any message for me ?</h2>
            }
          />
        </Router>
    );
  }
```

I'm still lost on how I would access the message being sent to this url.

Comment: Could you not rather do this with a fetch call in the first "tab"? If you open a new tab, that is basically a new process, and to do what you ask for will require quite a bit of nasty coding!

I think that it would be a good idea if you wrote what it is you want to achieve, cause I think that what you intend to do, could be done in a better way :)

Comment: Yes this does seem like a silly way to do things :) 
Well I essentially have 2 webs apps and need to open the second web app (new tab) from the first while also sending some data.
Fetch seems like a good way to do things but I'm still not sure how I would access the data being sent to the second tab. 
I'll update the question to also include the fetch option.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem for now by sending the data with `window.postMessage()` and accessing it in the new window by listening to the `message` event.